# Why can't I store a UIViewController in an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I'm learning Objective-C, and I'm currently trying to make transitions between view controllers works for iOS4/iOS5 devices (I'll do the same iOS5 only with storyboards after).

As I understood it, you instantiate only once you ViewControllers & you use `viewDidUnload` to release memory when the `viewController.view` is out of screen.

Examples I found did instantiate the next view controller in the method called when the buttonIsClicked. But let's say I want to go back & forth, I'm pretty sure this is not the right way (ie. if I want to keep form values, etc.).

So I gave all my viewControllers to my appDelegate, and then I wanted to store them inside a nice contained NSMutableDictionnary so that I could retreive one instance easily using :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIViewController *next = [appDelegate.controllers objectForKey:@"RegisterViewController"];
```

But... It does break everything (getting blank views).

I'd love to understand why.

---

This won't work :

```
[self.controllers setObject:[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] forKey:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.controllers setObject:[[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] forKey:@"RegisterViewController"];

self.window.rootViewController = [self.controllers objectForKey:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But this will :

```
UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
[self.controllers setObject:loginViewController forKey:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.controllers setObject:[[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] forKey:@"RegisterViewController"];

self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not instantating your dictionary - it remains nil and ignores all operations on itself. You have to alloc-init it before using it.